# Question about group $Aut(F/K)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I have an open question: if $F$ is an extension field of $K$, and $|Aut(F/K)|=[F:K]=p$ with $p$ is a prime and $p\neq char(K)$. So $F$ is a Galois extension of $K$ or not (if the answer is no, please give me an example)

Comment: Since you're inquiring about whether it is a Galois extension, and the Galois group is defined for Galois extensions, shouldn't you be asking about $Aut[F:K]$, the automorphisms of $F$ that fix $K$?

Comment: I read my book and it's define that if an automorphism of $F$ fixed all element in $K$ then all of that automorphisms creat a group called $Gal(F,K)$.

So the definition in my book itsn't true ?

Comment: @Zootopia It is usually defined as JasonM wrote to you.

Comment: @Zootopia It is more usually denoted by $\;Aut(F/K):=$ the group of all automorphisms of $\;F\;$  leaving $\;K\;$ fixed pointwise.

Comment: @Zootopia It's true that $Gal(F/K)=Aut(F/K)$, but we only talk about the former if $F/K$ is a Galois extension.

Comment: @Zootopia Also, it's not necessarily the case that $|Aut(F/K)|=[F:K]$ (it would be true for $Gal(F/K)$).  As an example, $Aut(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\Bbb{Q})=1$ while $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}):\Bbb{Q}]=3$.  So which one are you asking about constraining to $p$?